# complex case statement using LinQ to sql

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Here is the problem I am facing. 
Linqer had an issue converting the **When "H"**  part which contains another Case. Here is the original SQL:

```
    SELECT  [REC_FNAME] ,
            [REC_MNAME] ,
            [REC_LNAME] ,
            [REC_SLNAME] ,
            [ADDRESS_RECEIVER] ,
            [ID_CITY_RECEIVER] ,
            [ID_STATE_RECEIVER] ,
            [ZIP_RECEIVER] ,
            [ID_COUNTRY_RECEIVER] ,
            C.NAME_CITY ,
            ST.NAME_STATE ,
            CO.NAME_COUNTRY ,
            [PHONE1_RECEIVER] ,
            [PHONE2_RECEIVER] ,
            [NET_AMOUNT_RECEIVER] , -- send amount
            ISNULL([TELEX_RECEIVER], 0.00) , -- transfer fee
            [STATE_TAX] , -- source tax
            [DEST_COUNTRY_TAX] ,
            [TOTAL_RECEIVER] , -- total amount sent
            [RATE_CHANGE_RECEIVER] , -- exchange rate
            [TOTAL_PAY_RECEIVER] , -- receive amount
            [ID_CURRENY] ,
            [ID_FLAG_RECEIVER] ,
            CASE [ID_FLAG_RECEIVER]
              WHEN 'A' THEN 'VOID'
              WHEN 'C' THEN 'CANCEL'
              WHEN 'E' THEN 'EXPIRED'
              WHEN 'H'
              THEN ( SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   1
                                               FROM     [dba].[MOTIVO_HOLD] MH
                                                        WITH ( NOLOCK )
                                               WHERE    MH.ID_BRANCH = R.ID_BRANCH
                                                        AND MH.ID_RECEIVER = R.ID_RECEIVER
                                                        AND MH.TYPE_MOTIVO_HOLD = 70 )
                                 THEN 'STAGED'
                                 ELSE 'HOLD'
                            END
                   )
              WHEN 'I' THEN 'DONE'
              WHEN 'P' THEN 'PAID'
              WHEN 'T' THEN 'TRANSFERED'
            END AS TransactionStatus ,
            [RECEIVER_DATE_AVAILABLE] ,
            [DATE_RECEIVER] ,
            [CLAVE_RECEIVER] ,
            [ID_BRANCH] ,
            [ID_SENDER] ,
            [ID_RECEIVER] ,
            [BRANCH_PAY_RECEIVER]
    FROM    [dba].[RECEIVER] R
            INNER JOIN dba.STATE ST ON ST.ID_STATE = R.ID_STATE_RECEIVER
                                       AND R.ID_COUNTRY_RECEIVER = ST.ID_COUNTRY
            INNER JOIN dba.CITY C ON C.ID_CITY = R.ID_CITY_RECEIVER
                                     AND C.ID_STATE = R.ID_STATE_RECEIVER
                                     AND C.ID_COUNTRY = R.ID_COUNTRY_RECEIVER
            INNER JOIN dba.COUNTRY CO ON CO.ID_COUNTRY = ST.ID_COUNTRY
    WHERE   [ID_BRANCH] = @idBranch
            AND DATE_RECEIVER BETWEEN @startDate AND GETDATE()
            ORDER BY DATE_RECEIVER DESC
```

So I removed the  **When "H"**  and I got a statement that works: however I need to incorporate the "H" case to resolve what is the real description associated with it.

Help would be appreciated!

```
Here is the Linq statement I have to date:<br>
    var models1 =
            _context.Receivers
                .Where(r => r.ID_BRANCH == "A00070" &&
                            r.DATE_RECEIVER >=
                            (DateTime)
                                SqlFunctions.DateAdd(
                                    "day", -10,
                                    SqlFunctions.GetDate()) &&
                            r.DATE_RECEIVER <=
                            SqlFunctions.GetDate())
                .Join(_context.Senders,
                    r => new {r.ID_SENDER, r.ID_BRANCH},
                    s => new {s.ID_SENDER, s.ID_BRANCH},
                    (r, s) =>
                        new
                        {
                            s.NAME_SENDER,
                            r.NAME_RECEIVER,
                            r.TOTAL_PAY_RECEIVER,
                            Status =
                                r.ID_FLAG_RECEIVER.Replace("A", "VOID")
                                    .Replace("C", "CANCEL")
                                    .Replace("E", "EXPIRED")
                                    .Replace("I", "DONE")
                                    .Replace("P", "PAID")
                                    .Replace("T", "TRANSFERED")
                                    .Replace("H", "Hold"),
                            r.DATE_RECEIVER,
                            r.ID_CASHIER
                        })
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.DATE_RECEIVER)
                .Project().To<MoneyTransferListViewModel>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within LINQ, you would need to do it as a let keyword, which does a subquery, regardless of whether the item is H.  I don't think in LINQ you can do it in your scenario within the context of the replace.

The only thing is, I only know of a LINQ query way, which is:

```
from r in _context.Receivers
let b = (_context.Motivo_Hold
             .Where(i => i.ID_BRANCH == r.ID_BRANCH && i.ID_RECEIVER == r.ID_RECEIVER)
             .Select(i => new { .flag = 1 }))
.
select new { 
   .r.ID_FLAG_RECEIVER.Replace("A", "VOID")
     .Replace("H", (b.flag == 1 ? "Staged" : "Hold"))
}
```

Something like that...  Some of the syntax may be off, but that is the general approach

Comment: I will explore this other possibility.